# Better way to swap column values and then append them in a pandas dataframe?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

here  is my dataframe

```
import pandas as pd
data = {'from':['Frida', 'Frida', 'Frida', 'Pablo','Pablo'], 'to':['Vincent','Pablo','Andy','Vincent','Andy'],
       'score':[2, 2, 1, 1, 1]} 
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df
```

I want to swap the values in columns 'from' and 'to' and add them on because these scores work both ways.. here is what I have tried.

```
df_copy = df.copy()
df_copy.rename(columns={"from":"to","to":"from"}, inplace=True)
df_final = df.append(df_copy)
```

which works but is there a shorter way to do the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One line could be :

```
df_final = df.append(df.rename(columns={"from":"to","to":"from"}))
```

Comment: I added 'ignore_index=True' and its what I wanted. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

On the right track. However, introduce deep=True to make a true copy, otherwise your df.copy will just update df and you will be up in a circle.

```
    df_copy = df.copy(deep=True)
    df_copy.rename(columns={"from":"to","to":"from"}, inplace=True)
    df_final = df.append(df_copy)
```